# Is there a dead lock in the following go code? Not output though

Tags: concurrency, go

I am running the following [go code](http://play.golang.org/p/tDjEJKwkRJ) and it doesn't produce output:

```
package main

import "fmt"
//import "strconv"
import "time"

func Wait(){
    time.Sleep(2000 * time.Millisecond)
}

func Print(c chan string){
    fmt.Println("Running Print go-routine")
    for{
        fmt.Println("len(c): ", len(c))
        str := <- c
        fmt.Println(str)
    }
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan string, 4)
    c <- "0"
    c <- "1"
    c <- "2"
    c <- "3"
    Wait()
    fmt.Println("Before go Print(c)")
    go Print(c)
    fmt.Println("After go Print(c)")
}
```

Is there a deadlock? The `Print(c)` function is not even called...? Its very strange to me.
The link to it in go playground is: http://play.golang.org/p/tDjEJKwkRJ

Comment: always use `go run -race` to test that kind of code.

Comment: Your program exits before Print has any chance to print anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't an error, the Print() function is called in a goroutine, but the main program is exiting right after that... so the goroutine is terminated.

Read this talk: [Go Concurrency Patterns](http://talks.golang.org/2012/concurrency.slide#1) (or better, [view it's video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f6kdp27TYZs)), to understand how channels and goroutines work.

Keep in mind that the program is finished when the main function returns.

Answer (score 2):

When the `main` function invocation returns, the program exits. It does not wait for other (non-`main`) goroutines to complete.

Call your `Wait` function later, after the `go Print(c)` statement. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func Wait() {
    time.Sleep(2000 * time.Millisecond)
}

func Print(c chan string) {
    fmt.Println("Running Print go-routine")
    for {
        fmt.Println("len(c): ", len(c))
        str := <-c
        fmt.Println(str)
    }
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan string, 4)
    c <- "0"
    c <- "1"
    c <- "2"
    c <- "3"
    fmt.Println("Before go Print(c)")
    go Print(c)
    Wait()
    fmt.Println("After go Print(c)")
}
```

Output:

```
Before go Print(c)
Running Print go-routine
len(c):  4
0
len(c):  3
1
len(c):  2
2
len(c):  1
3
len(c):  0
After go Print(c)
```

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Program execution](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_initialization_and_execution)
>
> A complete program is created by linking a single, unimported package
>   called the main package with all the packages it imports,
>   transitively. The main package must have package name main and declare
>   a function main that takes no arguments and returns no value.
>
> ```
> func main() { … }
> ```
>
> Program execution begins by initializing the main package and then
>   invoking the function main. When that function invocation returns, the
>   program exits. It does not wait for other (non-main) goroutines to
>   complete.

Comment: Keep in mind that if this was a real program, `Print` would wait forever since you never close the channel or signal it to stop trying to read.

Comment: @OneOfOne: `Print` won't wait forever. It will be killed when `main` terminates.

Comment: I know that, I said "if this was a real program".

Comment: @OneOfOne: What do you mean by "a real program?"

Comment: A program that runs `go Print()` and doesn't exit right away, for example an http handler that starts it every time, this would be a memory leak since it doesn't exit, ever.